# Query aws to list all resources using boto3 python sdk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

Is there a way to get all the resources in the aws account through python code using boto3. I went through the documentation, didn't find any list function which might solve this.

Comment: You might also look at various GitHub projects e.g. [JohannesEbke/aws_list_all](https://github.com/JohannesEbke/aws_list_all).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this command.

but prerequisite enable `aws config` for this region before running this command.

```
import boto3

session = boto3.Session(profile_name=’your-profilename’)  
client = session.client(‘config’)  

resources = ["AWS::EC2::CustomerGateway", "AWS::EC2::EIP", "AWS::EC2::Host", "AWS::EC2::Instance", "AWS::EC2::InternetGateway", "AWS::EC2::NetworkAcl", "AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface", "AWS::EC2::RouteTable", "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup", "AWS::EC2::Subnet", "AWS::CloudTrail::Trail", "AWS::EC2::Volume", "AWS::EC2::VPC", "AWS::EC2::VPNConnection", "AWS::EC2::VPNGateway", "AWS::EC2::RegisteredHAInstance", "AWS::EC2::NatGateway", "AWS::EC2::EgressOnlyInternetGateway", "AWS::EC2::VPCEndpoint", "AWS::EC2::VPCEndpointService", "AWS::EC2::FlowLog", "AWS::EC2::VPCPeeringConnection", "AWS::IAM::Group", "AWS::IAM::Policy", "AWS::IAM::Role", "AWS::IAM::User", "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer", "AWS::ACM::Certificate", "AWS::RDS::DBInstance", "AWS::RDS::DBParameterGroup", "AWS::RDS::DBOptionGroup", "AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup", "AWS::RDS::DBSecurityGroup", "AWS::RDS::DBSnapshot", "AWS::RDS::DBCluster", "AWS::RDS::DBClusterParameterGroup", "AWS::RDS::DBClusterSnapshot", "AWS::RDS::EventSubscription", "AWS::S3::Bucket", "AWS::S3::AccountPublicAccessBlock", "AWS::Redshift::Cluster", "AWS::Redshift::ClusterSnapshot", "AWS::Redshift::ClusterParameterGroup", "AWS::Redshift::ClusterSecurityGroup", "AWS::Redshift::ClusterSubnetGroup", "AWS::Redshift::EventSubscription", "AWS::SSM::ManagedInstanceInventory", "AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm", "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack", "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer", "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup", "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration", "AWS::AutoScaling::ScalingPolicy", "AWS::AutoScaling::ScheduledAction", "AWS::DynamoDB::Table", "AWS::CodeBuild::Project", "AWS::WAF::RateBasedRule", "AWS::WAF::Rule", "AWS::WAF::RuleGroup", "AWS::WAF::WebACL", "AWS::WAFRegional::RateBasedRule", "AWS::WAFRegional::Rule", "AWS::WAFRegional::RuleGroup", "AWS::WAFRegional::WebACL", "AWS::CloudFront::Distribution", "AWS::CloudFront::StreamingDistribution", "AWS::Lambda::Alias", "AWS::Lambda::Function", "AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application", "AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ApplicationVersion", "AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment", "AWS::MobileHub::Project", "AWS::XRay::EncryptionConfig", "AWS::SSM::AssociationCompliance", "AWS::SSM::PatchCompliance", "AWS::Shield::Protection", "AWS::ShieldRegional::Protection", "AWS::Config::ResourceCompliance", "AWS::LicenseManager::LicenseConfiguration", "AWS::ApiGateway::DomainName", "AWS::ApiGateway::Method", "AWS::ApiGateway::Stage", "AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi", "AWS::ApiGatewayV2::DomainName", "AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Stage", "AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Api", "AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline", "AWS::ServiceCatalog::CloudFormationProvisionedProduct", "AWS::ServiceCatalog::CloudFormationProduct", "AWS::ServiceCatalog::Portfolio"]

for resource in resources:  
    response = client.list_discovered_resources(resourceType=resource)
    print(‘##################### {} #################’.format(resource)) 
    
    for i in range(len(response[‘resourceIdentifiers’])):
        print( ‘{} , {}’.format(response[‘resourceIdentifiers’][i][‘resourceType’], response[‘resourceIdentifiers’][i][‘resourceId’]))
```

Comment: running this on VScode. Throws the following error:SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xe2' in file c:\Users\rakshitas\Documents\AWS\demo.py on line 5, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details.

Comment: `# encoding=utf8` 
 just put the PEP-263 encoding comment at the top of the file:, helped?

Comment: was a minor one, changing the quotations removed the error. Thanks !

Comment: if it helped you, can you accept it as an answer to your solution so that it may help others in the future :)

Comment: @JatinMehrotra The `-1` in your `range` is leaving out the last object. In testing, removing it shows the expected results.

Comment: Feel free to edit it :) @MattW

Comment: @Jatin Mehrotra I'm getting "suggested edit queue is full"

Answer (score 5):

In boto3 you can use ResourceGroupsTaggingAPI method get_resources(). Which is used to get resources mainly based on tags but you can leave blank tag filter parameter and get all the resources supported.
Consider that not all resources are included and it is limited to a specific region but I hope that it can help you.

Examples:

Get all resources:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('resourcegroupstaggingapi')
client.get_resources()
```

Get resources of an especific service type:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('resourcegroupstaggingapi')
client.get_resources(
    ResourceTypeFilters=[
        'ec2:instance'
])
```

---

Official documentation:

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/resourcegroupstaggingapi.html#ResourceGroupsTaggingAPI.Client.get_resources

Comment: I tried this with 'ec2:security-group' and it only works for resources that have had tags at least once. It does NOT return those security groups that have never been tagged. Even stranger is that it returns objects that have been deleted. The boto3 documentation states, "*Returns all the tagged or previously tagged resources* that are located in the specified Amazon Web Services Region for the account" (https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/resourcegroupstaggingapi.html#ResourceGroupsTaggingAPI.Client.get_resources)

Comment: I am seeing the same issue, with not getting ec2:security-group listings for security groups without tags.

Comment: Seeing the same issue in the cli `aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources  --resource-type-filters ec2:security-group --region eu-central-1`, opening a ticket with AWS

Answer (score 3):

Following on from the answer Omar gave, I came up with the following:

```
from pprint import pprint

import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

client = boto3.client('resourcegroupstaggingapi', )
regions = boto3.session.Session().get_available_regions('ec2')

for region in regions:
    print(region)
    try:
        client = boto3.client('resourcegroupstaggingapi', region_name=region)
        pprint([x.get('ResourceARN') for x in client.get_resources().get('ResourceTagMappingList')])
    except ClientError as e:
        print(f'Could not connect to region with error: {e}')
    print()
```

which will loop most regions and list any ARNs in that region, like so:

```
eu-north-1
[]

eu-west-1
['arn:aws:mq:eu-west-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:broker:example:b-125099aa-8e22-462e-a8e9-bcc6b29c010a']

eu-west-2
[]

eu-west-3
[]
```